# How should i use asyncstorage.setItem in this fetch method?

Tags: react-native

i want to add the async storage method to save my json response,
but i don't know how to add there specifically

i have already tried like this

```
UserRegisterationFunction = () => {
    const { UserName } = this.state;
    const { UserEmail } = this.state;
    const { UserPassword } = this.state;

    fetch('http://192.168.1.7/test/user_registration.php', {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Accept' : 'application/json',
        'Content-Type' : 'application/json'
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        name: UserName,
        email: UserEmail,
        password: UserPassword
      })
    }).then((response) => response.json())
            .then((responseJson) => {
              AsyncStorage.setItem('token', responseJson)
              // this._onValueChange(STORAGE_KEY, responseData.id_token),
              Alert.alert(responseJson);
            }).catch((error) => {
              console.log(error)
            });
```

i am getting my alert successfully but i don't know how should i add the responseJson or if i have used it correctly or not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the asynchronous system or save successfully without using it.

To run asynchronously:

```js
            .then(async (responseJson) => {
             await AsyncStorage.setItem('token', responseJson.id_token);
              Alert.alert(responseJson);
            }).catch((error) => {
              console.log(error)
            });
```

If your responseJson data is this:

```
Object {
   id_token : "myid"
}
```

Use the `getItem` function on the following screen to check the value.

```js
async componentDidmount() {
 const tokens = await AsyncStorage.getItem('token');
 alert(tokens); // You can see 'myid'
}
```

Comment: how do i check if data is stored or not?

Comment: @someshbalani  I updated my answer. Could you check the 'V' sign if my answer was helpful?

Comment: i am not getting an alert of token, it just shows my alert of responseJson

Comment: `responseJson ` is an object. You can only store `string` values on storage. my answer has been modified. Please refer.

Comment: you see i am new to this so i am trying to learn as soon as possible sorry if you couldn't understand my problem clearly i just want to see the credentials of name email and password saved in my async storage, i want to view it on my console screen or through alert so if you could explain it to me clearly??

Comment: nothing is registering now my alert stopped when i added the modified code

Comment: @someshbalani I didn't save the object as if I were looking at the answer, but only the id value of the result. I don't know how you send data. That is why I have taken an example. Look at my answer.

Comment: @someshbalani Are you understand??

Comment: https://reactnativecode.com/react-native-user-registration-example-tutorial/ check this link i am following this code can you please check the obj you were talking about also how the data is sending is explained there you just tell me how would i be able to store my credentials through async storage?

Comment: You can already see what data is being received with the Alert. `Alert.alert(responseJson);`

Comment: When you look at the responseJson value, what does it say?

Comment: it says my data is stored $MSG = 'User Registered Successfully' ; this one

Comment: All right, then you have to change the price. `await AsyncStorage.setItem('token', responseJson.MSG);`

Comment: Then you can see this on the next screen when you see the alert. `"User Registered Successfully"`

Comment: the alert is not coming now

Comment: Is the screen that you see the data that you saved not the screen that you saved the data, but the next screen?

Comment: i don't have a next screen yet but i am going to create one with react navigation

Comment: You can see by my answer. I'm telling you to check the price on the next screen.

Comment: i will check and tell you after i had done it can you wait? i have checked the "V" mark thanks for helping

Comment: Create the next screen, check the results, and leave a comment if you have any problems.

Answer (score 0):

The JSON response is an object and you can't store the object directly in AsyncStorage. You can only store the object by converting it into a string.

To store the object:

```
AsyncStorage.setItem('KEY', JSON.stringify(object))
```

To retrieve the object:

```
const jsonObjectString = AsyncStorage.getItem('KEY')
const jsonObject = JSON.parse(jsonObjectString)
```